# VS2010 - How to work around "XXX is a reserved class name" error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I know you can’t add a class called “Socket” in VS2010 by doing:

- Right click on project
- Add -> Class
- C++ Class -> Add
- Type “Socket” as Class name and hit finish

You get:

```
'Socket' is a reserved class name
```

So instead I’ve tried adding a class called “Socket1”, removed all the occurrences of “1” and VS seems to compile without any errors.  Will this cause any conflict?  Or is using namespaces a proper way to work around the above error?

Comment: Just call it something else... SocketClass or something and not worry about any kind of problems?

Comment: You should always put your code into your own namespace (unless to achieve something it is absolutely necessary to put it elsewhere).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably just namespace it (and everything else you're writing for that matter), forcing your way around the compiler is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Rename the class** (putting it in a namespace was already suggested and it's another correct approach). The compiler is right to disallow this. Having multiple classes with the same name with different definitions is undefined behavior.